# Pandas: how to reuse the index information from the data?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [ ('id01', 'john', 23), ('id02', 'arquimedes', 42) ]
>>> pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'name', 'age'])
     id        name  age
0  id01        john   23
1  id02  arquimedes   42
```

I would like pandas to **not** use an extra index column, but to reuse my `id` column for the index. How can I configure this?

This is what I would like:

```
            name  age
id01        john   23
id02  arquimedes   42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'name', 'age']).set_index('id')
    name    age
id      
id01    john    23
id02    arquimedes  42
```

Alternatively, you can just create it with the index in place like this:

```
>>> data = [ ('john', 23), ('arquimedes', 42) ]
>>> pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'age'], index=['id0', 'id1'])
    name    age
id0     john    23
id1     arquimedes  42
```

Note that this creates a slightly different result - the index is not named.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But is it not possible to create the dataframe *already* using index information from the data. The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Index.html) seems to suggest is is possible (*Index to use for resulting frame. Will default to np.arange(n) if no indexing information part of input data and no index provided*), but I do not know how

Comment: Your updated answer not working for me with error `AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns`

Comment: Ok, thanks. From what you describe, either I do set_index, or I have to pre-process the data myself before creating the dataframe. Both methods are not what I expected: I expected to be able to tell pandas "create a dataframe with this data and, by the way, column 0 in the data is the index". At least that is my interpretation of the documentation, but I do not find aynwhere how to do this.

Comment: Yes, those seem to be the options - at least to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best is to use `set_index` (as far as I know). But if you want to create it without `reset_index` you could preprocess your data for appropriate shape with `zip`:

```
ind = list(zip(*data))[0]
dat = list(zip(*list(zip(*data))[1:]))

In [48]: dat
Out[48]: [('john', 23), ('arquimedes', 42)]

In [50]: ind
Out[50]: ('id01', 'id02')

In [52]: pd.DataFrame(dat, index=ind)
Out[52]: 
               0   1
id01        john  23
id02  arquimedes  42
```

Or if you prefer one line:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*list(zip(*data))[1:])), index=list(zip(*data))[0])
```

Showing some `zip` magic:

```
In [53]: list(zip(*data))
Out[53]: [('id01', 'id02'), ('john', 'arquimedes'), (23, 42)]

In [54]: list(zip(*data))[1:]
Out[54]: [('john', 'arquimedes'), (23, 42)]

In [55]: list(zip(*list(zip(*data))[1:]))
Out[55]: [('john', 23), ('arquimedes', 42)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this means pre-processing the data. I expected that this was supported by the `DataFrame` constructor